# MySQL - error 1045 - Access denied from shell

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that involves access to database. The credentials used are not from user X. whan I run the script from the browser, no problem.

But when I run from the shell (or a cron job), i get an error:

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>   PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: conn in....

If I run from the shell, logged as user X, same error.

The function inside the script that makes problem:

```
function get_data_from_db($sql){// 
    $hostdb=DB_HOST; //DB credentials are stored in php.ini, retrieved in another part of the script
    $namedb=DB_NAME;
    $userdb=DB_USER;
    $pwddb=DB_PASS;

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb;", $userdb, $pwddb);
        $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }   
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement;
```

}

I aldo tried with credentials from root user, same problem

Below, the function that gets the credentials, fails when run from the CLI

```
function loadConfig( $myapp, $vars = array() ) {
    foreach( $vars as $v ) {
        define( $v, get_cfg_var( $myapp.".cfg.$v" ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the script isn't sending the database username and password correctly. Post the script, including how you're setting these parameters.

Comment: When I launch the script from the browser, the script (using user X credentials) works OK. But if I do it from the command line, I get the error. I wish somebody could explain me the why? I have browes on SO overflow extensively, trying to find a hint, without success

Comment: You're getting the DB credentials from `php.ini`. There's often a different `php.ini` for the webserver and for CLI, it sounds like you don't have the credentials in `cli/php.ini`.

Comment: What does `var_dump($pwddb);` show when you run it from the shell?

Comment: It appears the credentials are returned correctly when the script is run from the browser, and are empty when run from the shell. I added above the function that gets the credentials in php.ini file, using get_cfg_var()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the database credentials to the CLI version of `php.ini`. They're currently only in the CGI or PHP-FPM version (whichever is used by your web configuration).